# Javascript date time two hours off

Tags: javascript, html, time

I have a javascript code set into my webpage but the date time is always two hours off. If anyone knows what's wrong please help.

**Here's my relevant JavaScript code:**

```
function show() {
    var Digital = new Date()
    var hours = Digital.getHours()
    var minutes = Digital.getMinutes()
    var seconds = Digital.getSeconds()
    var dn = "AM"
    if (hours > 12) {
        dn = "PM"
        hours = hours - 12
    }
    if (hours == 0) c
    hours = 12
    if (minutes <= 9)
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    if (seconds <= 9)
        seconds = "0" + seconds
    document.dform.currenttime.value = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + dn
    setTimeout("show()", 1000)
}
show();
```

Comment: please elaborate your goal on this code.

Comment: Timezones is a possibility

Answer (score 3):

**You have a `c` right here:**

```
if (hours==0)c
```

Delete the `c`. It works. You're welcome.

I suggest [*proofreading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofreading) your code before you come asking for help, but more importantly you should format your code so that it's legible enough to proofread. As an example:

```
function show() {
    var Digital = new Date();
    var hours = Digital.getHours();
    var minutes = Digital.getMinutes();
    var seconds = Digital.getSeconds();
    var dn = "AM";

    if(hours > 12) {
        dn = "PM";
        hours -= 12;
    }

    if(hours == 0) hours = 12;
    if(minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if(seconds <= 9) seconds = "0" + seconds;

    document.dform.currenttime.value = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + dn;
}

var clock = setInterval(show, 1000);
```

This is easier to read and you likely would've noticed the erroneous `c`.

Comment: thanks man i very much appreciate the help. I've done java before in high school. Haven't messed with it since. Sorry for the illegible code.

Comment: no problem, we're here to help. for your sanity and others, clean code is important. hopefully my answer doesn't come off as rude, just trying to point you in the right direction. clean code is easier to fix.